# How to import a module of functions and pass variables between modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module, global

A file 'Definitions.py' contains the code:

```
def testing(a,b):
    global result
    for count in range(a,b):
        result.append(0)
    print result
```

While file 'Program.py' contains the code:

```
from Definitions import *
result = []
testing(0,10)
print result
```

The result of the Definitions.py is the expected list of zeros, while the variable within Program.py is just the empty list despite results being defined as a global variable. How can this be made to run the function from Definitions.py but pass the resulting variable to be used within Program.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global namespaces are relative to a module. They are not shared between modules.

You could return the `result`:

```
def testing(a,b):
    result = []
    for count in range(a,b):
        result.append(0)
    return result
```

and use it like this:

```
result = testing(0,10)
print result
```

But note that above, a new list, `result = []`, is being created in `testing` each time it is called.

Comment: That's a good point, but what if the 'testing' function where to create two variables? Say result1 and result 2. How would I get result 1 and result2 both into Program.py? Setting result1 = testing(0,10) would not work then as it will be returning result1 and result 2.

Comment: You could return a tuple of objects: `return result1, result2`. And you could unpack them on the other side with `result1, result2 = testing(0, 10)`.

Comment: Oh yes, and then I would set result1 = testing(0,10)(0)?? Or something to grab the first element?

Comment: @DanReardon you can grab both : `result1,result2=testing(0,10)`, or to grab only one `result1=testing(0,10)[0]`.

Comment: Brilliant, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The global scope only applies to the module (file) that it's in.

Comment: Oh well that's a bit of a waste then.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The global for `testing` is the global namespace  of the `Definitions.py` , i.e the location where `def testing(a,b)` was defined. So, it can't see/access the `result` in `Program.py`.